# Hello I have a compiling issue, no matter what I seem to do I can't get rid of this error

Tags: java, drjava

I am currently working in drjava. Everything in the code below compiles but line 18, which generates the following error:

> Error: Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement

Can someone help me fix this?

This is the code:

```
    public class ProgramAssignmentPart1 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[]Students = new String[10];
    int[]Scores = new int[10];
    maxgrade = -99;
    mingrade = 200;
    int totalSum = 0;
    maxindex =11 ;
    minindex = 0 ;

   //double(100-score)/100(this is used somewhere)

   for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
   students[i] =input.next();
   scores[i] = input.nextInt();
   // and this needs to be pieced together below
   int currentS(i) = 0;
   if(currentS > maxgrade){
   maxgrade=currentS; maxgrade=i;

   if(scores[i] > maxgrade){
   maxgrade = score[i]; maxindex=i;
   }//reset max grades
    }

    if(currentS<minGrade){
    mingrade = currentS;
    minindex=i;

    if(scores[i]<mingrade){
    mingrade=scores[i];
    minindex=i;
    }
      totalsum+=currentS;
    }//loop
       System.out.println("Max.Grade"+Scores[maxindex]+"C"+Students[maxindex]+")");
       System.out.rintln("Min.Grade="+Scores[minindex]+("+Students[minindex]+")");
      }
     }
    }
```

Comment: Which line is 18? Note also that properly indenting your code (I believe DrJava will do this for you) makes it massively easier to spot this sort of error.

Comment: `int currentS(i) = 0;` looks wrong, `System.out.rintln("Min.Grade=" + Scores[minindex] + ("+Students[minindex]+")");` is wrong for two reasons, but there's too much code missing to be 100% of all the fixes

Comment: Is this the actual code you're using? There are so many compile errors here. Java is case-sensitive, so you can't use `Scores` and then `scores`.

Comment: Proper use of whitespace is something you should learn early on.  Humans tend to read things in words separated by spaces, and compilers support having key elements separated by spaces, so why write your code such that we have `int[]Scores` which mixes the type with the name.  `int[] scores` is much nicer as it first presents the type, then the name.

Answer (score 1):

There's a ***lot*** of compiler errors here, but the compiler messages you're getting aren't helpful.  Let's start from the top:  try compiling it with `javac` instead, and you should get more meaningful compilation errors.

I won't go through them one by one, since they're so numerous, but here are the highlights:

- All declared variables must have a type assigned to them.
- Variable naming is case sensitive; `var1` is different than `Var1`, which is different than `vAr1`.
- Spelling of function names is important, otherwise Java will tell you that it "cannot find symbol".

Answer (score 0):

i think when you said `int current(i) = 0;` you meant to make an integer that is the value of i?. it should be `int current = i;`

now the following code has some misplaced quotations:

```
System.out.rintln("Min.Grade="+Scores[minindex]+("+Students[minindex]+")");
```

it should be

```
System.out.rintln("Min.Grade=" + Scores[minindex]+ "(" + Students[minindex] + ")");
```

also make sure that when you write your variables you spell them correctly (they are K-sensitive), Be careful.